# Bulk Insert Connector getting index of current index

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am trying to do a bulk insert where I have to reference a variable in the payload.

```
    <db:sql >#['INSERT INTO public."PERSON_TBL" (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, ADDRESSES) 
            VALUES 
            (:firstnameParam,
             :lastnameParam,
             ' ++ "'$(someVariable)'" ++ ')']
   </db:sql>
```

In the example above, "ADDRESSES" is a DB column of type 'text[]'. Because of this I have to pass my array as a string something that looks like '{"Address1", "Address2"}'. The problem comes when this is a bulk insert and "someVariable" is just one of many within the payload. The question is: How do I set the exact "someVariable" for the current step. How can I get a reference to that? Is it something like

```
$(payload[currentIndex].someVariable)
```

Please help with this.

Comment: Please add the version of Mule, version of the Database connector (if Mule 4), the complete XML of the operation (where is the bulk insert?) and what is `someVariable` exactly? For example in Mule 4 variables are of the form vars.someVariable.

Comment: Can you please also mention the DB engine that you are using to check if the prepared statement support sending these types of values as parameter? The string you mention can be creates with `write(vars.someVariable,"application/json")` but I'm not sure if that solves the issue.